# Update menu from within RxSwift subscribe

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, rx-swift

I am updating a menu (adding, deleting item) from within a RxSwift subscriber. This is how the menu supposed to look like:

[image]

The "Item A" will be continuously added and removed, depending on changes of the model, like the following:

```
// Using ObservableArray (https://github.com/safx/ObservableArray-RxSwift)
model.changeset.rx()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { (changes) in

            // Inserts
            for change in changes.insertedElements {
                guard let item = self.newItem(item: change) else { continue }
                let index = (self.view?.indexPlaceholder(at: .specialItem) ?? 0) + 1
                // self.view is a NSMenu Object, so menu item will be added here
                self.view?.insertItem(bridgeItem, at: index)
            }

            // Deletes
            for change in changes.deletedElements {
                guard let menuItems = self.view?.getItems(withIdentifier: .specialItem) else { continue }
                guard let newIndex = menuBridgeObjects.firstIndex(where: {
                    ...
                }
                
                let index = (self.view?.indexPlaceholder(at: .specialItem) ?? 0) + 1 + index
                // self.view is a NSMenu Object, so menu item will be removed here
                self.view?.removeItem(safe: index, onlyIf: .specialItem)
            }

        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The `model.changeset` will be populated or altered based on several network activities running in the background.

However, I have realized that while the menu is open, any modifications to the `model.changeset` and the menu changes through the subscriber, the menu looks like this (missing the separator item below "Item A"):

[image]

After closing the menu (tracking lost) and re-open again (no changes on the model this time, so code snippet above will not be triggered), the menu looks as it was supposed to be like this:

[image]

I already tried something like `NSMenu.update()`, but this is somehow not helping to draw the NSMenu properly while open. Do you know if I have overseen something very important here?

Answer (score 2):

> The code above will be enabled and triggered immediately after NSMenu's delegate `func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu)`

The above feels wrong to me. You should instead setup the code to trigger any time the array changes, don't tie it to `menuWillOpen(_:)`. That way the menu items array will always be in the correct state when the menu opens.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The subscribe via RxSwift is done during boot up of the app. However, the dynamical adding or removing of the menu items should be triggered whenever the user opens the menu. But you say that it should be rather updated in the background on regular basis, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: I have realized that there is not direct connection between calling `menuWillOpen(_:)` and the observer for `model.changeset`. Even after de-coupling from `menuWillOpen(_:)` and let the update run in the background, the issue is still there.